# Post form using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have problem in submit file. The submit coding is working on my wampserver.
But When i load it to server. Post method is not working. Following are the code.

```
var datastring = $("#aprovel_form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "db/suppler_add_to_job_db.php",
                data: datastring,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); if the dataType is not specified as json uncomment this
                    // do what ever you want with the server response
                    alert(data);
                 window.location.replace("http://www.tesiy.com/abcmail/rasasaree_system_part_2/pages/?page=supplier/add_suppler_from_begin");   
                },
                error: function(){
                      alert('error handing here');
                }
            })
```

I get the alert('error handing here'). Please help me.

Comment: the `error` callback has a parameter usually telling you, what went wrong

Comment: Where is your **datastring**?

Comment: Datastring is the value of the form which serialized is.

Comment: Check your console upon submit for possible `404` not found errors (_using firebug on Firefox recommended_).

Comment: Look at your browser's JS console, it will probably have useful error messages. Look at your browser's Net tab, it will show you what data you are actually sending and what the server is responding with. The `error` function takes three arguments. Look at their values instead of alerting a hard coded and unhelpful error message.

Comment: i have tried by using getElemendById method and put the values to alert.It has worked. But when i had added the same coding in post method, then it has not worked. I find that trouble in $.post(...) is. But i don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @sanji — While attempting additional debugging techniques is great, you don't appear to have followed any of the advice given to you in the comments that will help you identify what the problem is. Try following it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys. Finally i find the problem. The  suppler_add_to_job_db.php file was not complete uploaded. It was damaged. That's why the post method was working. Anyway thanks for your helps friends.